# Unix shell script, parameters with spaces

Tags: shell-script

I need to make a shell script called `chExt.sh`. that accepts a file extension and then multiple files.  It then needs to change the file extensions or state that the file does not exist.

`./chExt.sh txt ocelot.cpp ../otherFolder/file.H cat.dog.TXT king cobra.dat` is the general idea of the auto testers test.  The problem is that I haven't the faintest clue how to deal with the one file with a space in it's name.

my code is:

```
newExt="$1"
shift
for x in $*
do
    fileName="$x"
    if test -f "$fileName";
    then
        name=$(echo "$fileName" | rev | cut -f 2- -d '.' | rev)
        newName="$name.$newExt"
        if test "$newName" != "$fileName";
        then
            mv "$x" "$newName"
        fi
    else
        echo "$fileName: No such file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: The file with spaces in its name must be escaped in the argument. `king\ cobra.dat` or `"king cobra.dat"`

Comment: I fixed the missing quotes in your code. Since you're not mentioning syntax errors, I assumed they were just copying errors and your actual code ios correctly quoted.

Comment: I'm confused ... `$()` is kind of a Bashism ... at least not supported in pure POSIX shells. Why don't you make use of string substitution to cut off the extension (`${i%.*}`) and of `"$@"` in the `for` loop? After all you seem to have some shell available which allows this.

Comment: @0xC0000022L it is most certainly not a bashism! [It's POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), just not supported by some older shells.

Comment: @terdon: so where did it originate then? Not in the Bourne shell or the C shell to my knowledge. I wrote "kind of" *intentionally* to signify that this would be more commonly seen in Bash or Bash-inspired shells rather than in the stock `sh` on any given system. AFAIK a lot of features were pioneered and spread by particular shells and later standardized in SUS.

Comment: @0xC0000022L no idea. I just know that it is POSIX and that most modern shells do support it and in fact recommend it over the backticks. I don't know of any system likely to be around today whose stock `sh` doesn't support it. I'm sure such systems exist, but they won't be many. I just tested and it works for ash, bash, dash, sh (bash called as `sh`), fish, csh, ksh, tcsh and zsh. That's all the shells I have installed.

Comment: @terdon: Try FreeBSD 10.2 `sh` some time ... I just tripped over this recently.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't quote the file name, the shell has no way of knowing that `foo bar.txt` is one parameter and not two (`foo` and `bar.txt`). You therefore need to call your script like this:

```
./chExt.sh txt ocelot.cpp ../otherFolder/file.H cat.dog.TXT "king cobra.dat"
```

The next problem is that when variables are expanded, the resulting value [is split on whitespace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109074/22222) (or whatever the `$IFS` variable is set to). So, when you write `for i in $*`, the `$*` is expanded and split on whitespace. Therefore, `$i` becomes `king` for one iteration and `cobra.txt` for the next. The way around that is to quote the variable you want to expand so that it is not split.

Which brings us to the next issue which is the [difference between `$*` and `$@`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/22222). If you use `"$*"`, the parameters will all be treated as one long string:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
for i in "$*"; do
    echo "$i"
done
$ foo.sh foo "bar baz"
foo bar baz
```

Compare the above to:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in "$@"; do
    echo "$i"
done
$ foo.sh foo "bar baz"
foo
bar baz
```

As you can see, using `"$@"` has the desired effect, each input parameter is treated separately, including the one with spaces.

As a final note, your script will also choke on file names starting with `-` and a letter corresponding to an option for `echo` (try with a file called `-new`, for example). A better way to strip the extension is to use the shell's native [string manipulation features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). `${var%.*}` removes the shortest string matching a `.` and 0 or more characters from the end of the variable. In other words, the extension. Then, you also need to add `--` to `mv` to indicate the end of option and the start of parameters so that it too can deal with file names starting with `-` (see Guideline 10 [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)).

So, an improved and working version of your script would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
newExt="$1"
shift
for fileName in "$@"
do
    if test -f "$fileName";
    then
    #    name=$(echo "$fileName" | rev | cut -f 2- -d '.' | rev)
    name=${fileName%.*}
        newName="$name.$newExt"
        if test "$newName" != "$fileName";
        then
            mv -- "$fileName" "$newName"
        fi
    else
        printf '%s: No such file\n' " $fileName"
    fi
done
```

Further reading:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222)

Comment: The `for i do` syntax (instead of `for i in "$@"; do`) removes the danger of forgetting to quote the `$@`.

Comment: @Kusalananda hmm, yes good point. I personally never use the `for i do` syntax because I find the explicit mention of `"$@"` more clear and readable (OK, also because I simply didn't know about `for i do` until a couple of years ago :P). But yes, you're quite right.

Comment: As far as I understand, it's a relatively recent addition to the POSIX shell grammar (but I don't know _how_ recent, it may still be quite old). I'm sure someone in the POSIX loop knows exactly when it was included.

Answer (score 1):

Another noteworthy quality about `"$*"` and `"$@"` is that they represent the shell array - the current set of the shell's arguments. These are changeable with the `set` built-in, but are more generally the default operational array for any built-in array functions - to include the `for` array.

```
: "${2?no file arguments!}"
for x 
do     if    [ "${2+:}" ]
       then  set ".$1"
       else  [ ".${x##*.}" != "$1" ] &&
             [ -f "$x" ] &&
             mv -- "$x" "${x%.*}$1"
       fi
done
```

That's a pretty close approximation to what your script does. It is a little different in that it doesn't do the `echo` for an argument which is not a regular file. I'm not certain you're doing what it is you think you are there, though: you're checking if your argument is an existing, accessible, *regular file*, but you're `echo`ing a message to stdout which says *argument: No such file*. On a unix-like system everything is a file: a pipe is a file, a directory is a file, a device is a file. And so your test and your message don't align. What's more, if you asked `mv` to move a non-existent file, it would print your message for you, and to stderr - all on its own.

Another thing I notice is that you're testing if your newname equals your old name, and I assume this is to avoid `mv` complaining about moving a file over itself. As it happens, `mv` has an option for quieting that.

I think I would do your thing like:

```
: "${2?no file arguments!}"
for x 
do     [ "${2+:}" ] &&
       set -- ".$1" && continue
       set -- "${x%.*}$1" "$1"
{      [  -e "$1" ] && printf "%s: exists!\n" "$1"; } ||
{    ! [  -f "$x" ] && printf "%s: not a regular file.\n" "$x"; } ||
       mv -f --    "$x" "$1"
       shift
done   >&2
```