# understanding .sh file terminology and cmake

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cmake

I am trying to use cmake and OpenGL to learn computer graphics, and the tutorial included a run.sh file that is supposed to compile/build the cpp programs. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#calls cd build 
#cmake .. -DSRC<argument> && make argument

EMBEDDED=`echo $2`
DIRECTORY=`echo $1 |cut -d'/' -f1`
FILENAME=`echo $1 |cut -d'/' -f2 |cut -d'.' -f1 | sed -e "s|/|_|g"`
TARGET=${FILENAME}

mkdir build
cd build
rm bin/${TARGET}
cmake .. -DSRC=../$1
make VERBOSE=1
bin/${TARGET}
```

From my understanding, mkdir creates a build directory, then we 'cd' into that directory, remove something from the previous build, cmake the actual file, I have no idea what make "VERBOSE=1" does, and then I am thinking we access the executable in the last line.

I do not understand what the middle block of code that starts with EMBEDDED does, neither am I sure about what the third comment "#cmake ..." does. I am using cpp files, and I think I have to pass the file as a command line argument along with ./run.sh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### overly complicated assignment

```
EMBEDDED=`echo $2`
```

This takes the second argument to the script and [performs a split and a glob on it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108963/expansion-of-a-shell-variable-and-effect-of-glob-and-split-on-it) (surprise!) and passes the result of that to `echo` and then assigns the result of whatever `echo` does (which, owing to creeping featurism, [may not be an echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)) to `EMBEDDED`. This is probably more sensibly written using a simple

```
EMBEDDED=$2
```

assignment statement.

### overly complicated file path component determination

```
DIRECTORY=`echo $1 |cut -d'/' -f1`
```

This could be more intentfully written using the `dirname(1)` command with also `""` to eliminate the POSIX split and glob as one probably does not want whatever results from the (surprise!) split and glob gunking up what gets assigned to `DIRECTORY`.

```
DIRECTORY=`dirname "$1"`
```

However, `dirname` and `cut -d'/' -f1` are not the same unless the only input is `somedirectory/somefile`. Someone would need to understand the inputs to the code to know whether the simplification to `dirname` can be made. The expected inputs are not documented in the script posted in the question—are they documented anywhere?

On a related note there is a `basename(1)` command that may help with

```
FILENAME=`echo $1 |cut -d'/' -f2 |cut -d'.' -f1 | sed -e "s|/|_|g"`
```

though it appears this pipeline with `cut -d'.' -f1` attempts to obtain a `prefix` from `prefix.whatever`, and I have no idea what the `sed -e "s|/|_|g"` is for, as `/` cannot appear in filenames. If there are `_` in the argument being passed it would be more sensible to pass them as `_` and not add extra code to change `/` into `_`. So probably the above could be simplified to

```
FILENAME=`basename "$1" | cut -d'.' -f1`
```

### needlessly dangerous commands

```
mkdir build
cd build
rm bin/${TARGET}
```

This sequence may or may not create a `build` directory and then will try to delete various things from either the new `build` directory or on failure the parent of that. This is sloppy and indeterminate. And by various things I mean that `${TARGET}` will be expanded with the POSIX shell split and glob so may contain quite unexpected filenames—luckily the `rm` is not the usual "oh yeah, about that filesystem you just lost" `rm -rf` so the hilarity will be limited to various (still surprising!) filenames, possibly from the wrong directory.

(Some might argue that configuration management or at least [guarded commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language) should be used instead of fragile and error prone shell scripts, but here we are...)

```
[ -d build ] || { mkdir build; [ -d build ] || exit 1; }
cd build || exit 1
rm bin/"${TARGET}"
cmake .. -DSRC=../"$1" && make VERBOSE=1 && bin/"${TARGET}"
```

Here `build` is a directory, is made as a directory, or failing that the script bails (you could also add a custom error message though `mkdir` typically makes noise). This is not atomic in that something else could `touch build` between the `-d` check and subsequent `mkdir`, so another approach is to "make the directory and then inspect the result to see whether it was a failure (not ok) or `EEXIST` on a directory (ok). `cd` is also checked for failures, and `$TARGET` quoted to prevent the POSIX split and glob thing.

Comment: I would have used `mkdir -p build || exit 1` instead of that slightly too complex thing you have, and `rm -f "bin/$TARGET"` to have `rm` not say anything if the file is missing. I would also have dropped those `{...}` around variables when they're not needed.

Comment: I keep forgetting about `mkdir -p` (though wanted also to show the full Guarded Commands Logic (which probably should be hidden behind an interface))