# Create user with password, check if user exists and add him to a group

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to write a bash script which will

1. check if it is run as `root` user
2. ask for the user name
3. check if user exists
4. add new user with password
5. ask for the group name
6. check if this group exists
7. add the user to the group

I wrote code like this

```sh
function create_user() {
if (( $EUID == 0)); then
echo "Only for root users."
exit
fi
echo "User name: "
read userschool
for x in $(awk -F":" '{ print }' /etc/passwd ); do
if [ $x == userschool ] ; then
echo "This user exists"
sleep $delay_time && exit
fi 
done
sudo useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 $PASS) $userschool
echo "User has been added"
sleep $delay_time
echo "Name of group"
read school
for x in $(awk -F":" '{ print }' /etc/group ); do
if [ $x == school ] ; then
echo "Group doesn't exists"
else
echo "$userschool has been added to group $school"
sleep $delay_time
break 2
fi
done
}
```

It almost works but if the user exists the script also adds him one more time and I don't know why. I want to communicate that the user exists and stop.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly recommend you learn to indent your code so that blocks (loops) stand out. It makes writing (and debugging) so much easier

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing `$x` with literal `userschool` not as variable. And you should double quote your variable calls to [prevent globbing and word splitting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108963/expansion-of-a-shell-variable-and-effect-of-glob-and-split-on-it). It should be :

```
if [ "$x" == "$userschool" ]; then
...
fi

if [ "$x" == "$school" ]; then
...
fi
```

And you don't have to iterate the whole /etc/passwd and make comparison line by line. Instead, just do:

```
awk -F: -v user=$userschool '$1 == user {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Where `-v` is a variable assignment in awk.

If it's already exist, then it will output given username

```
# Since it's bash, you can do this instead
read -p "Username: " userschool
exists=$(awk -F: -v user=$userschool '$1 == user {print $1}' /etc/passwd)

if [[ "$exists" ]]; then
  echo "User exists."
  sleep $delay_time
  exit 1
fi 

# create user
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problems are the

```
awk -F":" '{ print }' /etc/passwd
```

which prints the whole line. It must be

```
awk -F":" '{ print $1; }' /etc/passwd
```

and that you forgot the `$` in `$x == userschool`. That must be `"$x" = "$userschool"`, of course.

Furthermore it doesn't make sense to call `exit` with

```
sleep $delay_time && exit
```

because you want the `exit` to be executed in any case. But it is not if there are problems with `sleep` (e.g. if you forgot to set `delay_time` or gave it an illegal value). So that should be

```
E_USER_EXISTS=3
if [ "$x" = "$userschool" ] ; then
    echo "This user exists"
    sleep "$delay_time"
    exit "$E_USER_EXISTS"
fi
```

Nonetheless, this is a terrible approach. I will suggest a better one later.

Comment: It's not solve my problem unfortunately. There is still communicate that user exists and later that has been added.

Comment: @LauroMike There are a lot of problems in your code. I fixed one/two more fatal errors.

Comment: cold you tell me where is these fatal errors?

Comment: @LauroMike As it says in my answer: (1) You forgot the `$` in `$x == userschool`. (2) You executed `exit` conditionally i.e. depending on the other script code (which you haven't shown to us) or the environment the `exit` would not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

By default, useradd command throws error if user exists already...you don't have to recheck it...

```
function create_user() {
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
 echo "This script must be run as root" 
 exit 1
fi
echo -n "User name: "
read userschool
sudo useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 $PASS) $userschool && echo "User has been added"
sleep $delay_time
echo "Name of group"
read school
sudo groupadd $school &>>/dev/null && echo "Group created $school"
sudo usermod -aG $school $userschool
}
```

Comment: It's working very good but I still have problem with exists user because If there will be user which exists, there is communication about this and next I can add him to group one more time.