# Expand a wildcard matching single directory/file

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

This works beautifully in BASH:

```bash
$ where=/sys/class/backlight/*
$ echo $where
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
```

However when put in the POSIX script with `/bin/sh` as an interpreter, this doesn't work, `where` becomes `/sys/class/backlight/*`.

I've tried to Google but probably I'm not using the right terms.

Comment: You didn't show us HOW you put it in the script.

Comment: No - thats not even the complete line from your script, nevermind how you subsequently reference the values

Comment: The script as posted on PasteBin works for me in bash, ksh and dash.

Comment: Probably a bug in the un-shown script. Solution: fix script.  (This is the best that can be done with the given info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the variable `where` is always the string `/sys/class/backlight/*`. Generally speaking, there is no wildcard expansion in contexts where the syntax expects a single word, such as the right-hand side of a scalar assignment. There is wildcard expansion (and also word splitting) in contexts where the syntax expects a list of words, such as a command and its arguments, or the right-hand side of an array assignment. See [Expansion of a shell variable and effect of glob and split on it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108963/expansion-of-a-shell-variable-and-effect-of-glob-and-split-on-it/109074#109074) and [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748) for more details.

`$where` expands the wildcard if it's used in a list context. Presumably, in your script, you put `$where` in double quotes (which makes the whole thing a single word) or in some other word context.

If your script is a bash (not plain sh) script, you can make `where` an array:

```
where=(/sys/class/backlight/*)
```

Then you can use `"${where[@]}"` for the list of directories for backlight devices. Strangely, ksh made `$where` be equivalent to `${where[0]}`, i.e. taking the first element of the array and ignoring the rest, so if you're assuming that there's a single device, you can just keep using `$where` in a word context.