# How to use an escaped file-name string saved within a bash variable in a new shell command?

Tags: linux, bash

Problem:

I have an escaped string saved within a variable:

```
escapedFileName='/dbDumps/Mon\ Oct\ \ 1\ 15\:22\:50\ UTC\ 2018.sql'
```

but whenever I try to use this file name within the following command, I get an error message saying that this path does not exist (even though it does).

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -pmypassword system < "$escapedFileName";
```

When i use the path and not the string it works :

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -pmypassword system < /dbDumps/Mon\ Oct\ \ 1\ 15\:22\:50\ UTC\ 2018.sql
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @don_crissti that is not duplicate, in many ways it is the opposite.

Comment: so this is not a duplicate question ?

Comment: There's always a duplicate out there but someone has to find it... Here's a better candidate (I can no longer vote to close this one): [Why I can't escape spaces on a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108635/22142). Note that [only one answer there is correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108663/22142). Both _braiam_'s and _daisy_'s answers are _wrong_ (as you already know now) - double quoting the variable doesn't solve this problem. Not surprisingly, one of those answers is accepted and has an insane number of upvotes...

Comment: @don_crissti ^^ there you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape when you put the text between quotes.

Therefore remove the `\`s

```
escapedFileName='/dbDumps/Mon Oct  1 15:22:50 UTC 2018.sql'
```

And you should not escape the `:`, they don't need it, and it will break it.

Comment: @Kusalananda my bad, I was not thinking straight. I have now fixed my answer.

Comment: Not any quotes....straight quotes.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro single (`'`) of double (`"`), back quotes are deprecated, in favour of `$()`